# Finding the maximum of $f(x) = 2x\cos(2x) - (x-2)^2, [2,4]$ using the first derivative.

Tags: numerical-methods, maxima-minima

I am currently stuck on the part where we make the first derivative of a function equal to 0, I tried using trig identities and such but I couldn't make it zero.

we are given the following:

$$f(x) = 2x\cos(2x) - (x-2)^2, [2,4]$$

I find the derivative to be:

$$2\cos(2x) - 4x(\sin(2x)) - 2(x-2) = 0$$

At this point I am stuck with trying to either find the undefined or points in general that make the function **(f'(x))** equal to 0. How do I approach solving for x?

Comment: Is this an exercise for numerical calculation?

Comment: It's a review question for "Numerical Analysis", so it may seem really obvious to you and others.

Comment: I did graph it, and see where the maximum was, but that doesn't teach me how to find out what 'x' should be to make the first derivative equal to 0.

Comment: Have you learned Newton's method?

Comment: Then you could have asked your question in a better way by adding the "numerical analysis" information to your question. And all one needs now is to solve the equation $f'(x)=0$ numerically.

Comment: Was my thought on using trig identities to solve it correct, or am I missing something else as well?

Comment: trig identities won't save you here.

Comment: Ah darn, so what would be the best way for me to solve it by hand?

Comment: You have already said that this is a review question for "numerical analysis". Why would you expect that one should solve it by hand??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f'(x)=2\cos(2x)-4x\sin(2x)-2(x-2)$$
\begin{align}f''(x)&=-4x\sin(2x)-4\sin(2x)-8x\cos(2x)-2
\\&=-4(x+1)\sin(2x)-8x\cos(2x)-2\end{align}

$$\frac{f'(x)}{f"(x)}=-\frac{\cos(2x)-2x\sin(2x)-2(x-2)}{2(x+1)\sin(2x)+4x\cos(2x)+1}$$

From Newton's method

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f'(x_n)}{f"(x_n)}$$

I have coded some simple python code here:

http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user42_uBhUshL1Zh_0.py

the solution is roughly $3.13110627798$ and objective funciton  $4.98143395755$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Just for the fun and for your curiosity.*

If you plot the derivative of the function as a function of $x$, you should notice that it does cancel close to $x=\pi$. $$f'(x)=2\cos(2x)-4x\sin(2x)-2(x-2)\implies f'(\pi)=6-2\pi$$ Sooner or later, you will learn that we can approximate functions using the so-called [Pade approximants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) which are ratios of polynomials.

The simplest one would be $$f'(x) \approx \frac{-\frac{2 \left(19+2 \pi +16 \pi ^2\right) (x-\pi )}{1+4 \pi }-2 (\pi
   -3)}{1-\frac{6 (x-\pi )}{1+4 \pi }}$$ the solution of which being "simply" $$x=\frac{6+60 \pi -4 \pi ^2+32 \pi ^3}{38+4 \pi +32 \pi ^2}\approx 3.131107220$$ while the "exact"solution (Siong Thye Goh obtained it using Newton method) is $\approx 3.131106279$